# Звук при воспроизведении стал намного тише Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, аудио

В приложении есть кнопка которая при нажатии на которую воспроизводится звук, и вроде все было нормально но потом звук начал проигрываться намного тише... Вот код который я использую

```
audioButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.grammofo);
    audioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, SingletonForLetters.
                    getInstanceForLetters().getLetterses().get(position).getMuzik());
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Подскажите почему могло так произойти?

Comment: Это так называется метод в официальном API? `getLetterses`? `getMuzik`? о_О

Comment: вы когда проверяете в эмуляторе/телефоне, звук на устройстве не уменшали?

Comment: Нет звук не уменьшали...